# How to use toString method to convert my coordinates to up down left right

Tags: javascript, java, tostring

I want the `toString()` to return `[up, down, right,left]` rather than integers. For example,

```
new Direction(-1,1).toString() should give "<up right>".
new Direction(1,-1).toString() should give "<down left>"
new Direction(1,0).toString() should give "<down>"
new Direction(0,-1).toString() should give "<left>"
```

Comment: It seems like a simple case of if-else-if checks in toString() method, and you are about to get more downvotes than answers :(

Comment: lol why downvotes?

Comment: Probably because it is very basic in nature, plus the problem also has nothing to do with javascripting, so developers here are pretty sensitive to such issues. But I promise that I wasn't the one who downvoted :D

Comment: can you help i am very new to this please i need some help .

Comment: how do i use if else ?

Comment: iis it correct to write if ( new Direction(-1,1).toSrting())

Comment: By asking such a simple question you are actually saying you are not willing to do any research. That you are not prepared (or wanting) to learn. And this will most likely prevent other people from helping you.

Comment: @Jkae11 Ok there is an answer, and part of me strongly believes that you won't be able to compile it (Since you never showed the code for Direction class), but still you can get a very strong idea of where you are supposed to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are overriding the toString() method of your Direction class, also for the sake of your problem, let Direction.x and Direction.y be some variables in your Direction class (Which you never specified in the problem statement), you can go like this

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
   // Testing for (-1 , 1) 
   if( this.x < 0 && this.y > 0 )
   {
       return "<up right>";
   }
   // Testing for (1 , -1)
   else if( this.x > 0 && this.y < 0 )
   {
       return "<down left>"; 
   }
   // Testing for (1 , 0)
   else if( this.x > 0 && this.y == 0 )
   {
      return "<down>"; 
   } 
   // Since none of the above executed, we assume that it's (0 , -1) case
   else
   {
       return "<up>"; 
   }

}
```

So finally really your Direction class will have to look something like this to work properly

```
public class Direction
{
    // You are pretty new so I wouldn't confuse you with public,protected and private here
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Direction( int xArg , int yArg )
    {
        this.x = xArg;
        this.y = yArg; 
    }

    public Direction() // No-Arg Constructor, give default values here
    {
        // this could really be initialized to fit your taste 
        this.x = -1; 
        this.y = 1;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
       // Testing for (-1 , 1) 
       if( this.x < 0 && this.y > 0 )
       {
           return "<up right>";
       }
       // Testing for (1 , -1)
       else if( this.x > 0 && this.y < 0 )
       { 
          return "<down left>"; 
       }
       // Testing for (1 , 0)
       else if( this.x > 0 && this.y == 0 )
       {
          return "<down>"; 
       }  
       // Since none of the above executed, we assume that it's (0 , -1) case
       else
       {
           return "<up>"; 
       }

    }
}
```

I really can't tell how to make you understand a very basic if-else-if flow but after putting this code in your Direction class, and knowing that there is some int variable x and y, calling **new Direction(-1 , 1).toString();**  **new Direction(1,-1).toString();**  **new Direction(1,0).toString();** and **new Direction(0 , -1).toString()** will give you the appropriate result;